# Want to Toggle a hidden table, by clicking Toggled (Up/Down arrow images)

Tags: jquery, html

I am making a web project, and want to toggle a  by clicking on an image(Down arrow image) to show table. And (Up arrow image) to hide table.

I am using J Query for this purpose, table toggle is working but with images its not working. After first click it changes the image to a (source not found image). But table works fine.

I am sharing the code and screen shots of the web page. Need help in this matter, any kind of assistance would be appreciable to solve this problem Thanks!.![

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function (e) {
            $('#show1').click(function () {
               
                if ($("#show1",this).attr("src") == "~/Images/arrow1.png")
                {
                    $("#show1").attr("src", "~/Images/rarrow1.png");
                }
                else {
                    $("#show1").attr("src", "~/Images/arrow1.png");
                }
                    $('#show-list1').toggle("slow");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

```html
 <img style="margin-left:400px" align="right"  height="20" width="25"  id="show1" src="~/Images/arrow1.png" />


// 2nd image source is "~/Images/rarrow1.png"
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DIkl.jpg)

Comment: I am new to stack flow, having no reputation, can't add screen shots. Its more easy to understand through screen shot of this problem, anyway.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8krnnvuf/)

```js
$(".displayBlock").hide();
$('#toggleArrow').click(function () {
  var imageElement = document.getElementById('toggleArrow');
  if (imageElement.src.indexOf("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musthave/256/Stock%20Index%20Down.png") != -1) {
      $("#toggleArrow").attr("src", "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musthave/256/Stock%20Index%20Up.png");
  } else {
   $("#toggleArrow").attr("src", "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musthave/256/Stock%20Index%20Down.png");
  }
  $('.displayBlock').toggle("slow");
});
```

```css
#toggleArrow {
    float:right;
    margin-right:40px;
}
img {
    width:20px;
    height:30px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.displayBlock {
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    right:15px;
    padding:10px;
    background:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musthave/256/Stock%20Index%20Down.png" alt="Image Down" id="toggleArrow" />
<div class="displayBlock">
    <p>Hey, there i am display block</p>
    <p>I get toggle on Arrow clicks</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, working perfect.
"if" check with "(src.indexOf)" helped me alot.

Thanks alot for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is really simple
the JS code is: `document.getElementById("element id here").hiden = true (or false)`

`element.hidden` will return either `true` or `false`, and can be changes using the above code.

for example, check out this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ProgrammerKid/ywj7w0sp/

if you need extra help, just post a comment

Comment: Thank you for your help @(Viraj Shah), but I had the problem with the images not with the table toggle. But its working now.

Comment: Code:

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function (e) {
            $('#show1').click(function () {
                var imageElement = document.getElementById('show1');
                if (imageElement.src.indexOf("Images/arrow1.png") != -1) {
                    $("#show1").attr("src", "Images/rarrow1.png");
                } else {
                    $("#show1").attr("src", "Images/arrow1.png");
                }
                $('#show-list1').toggle("slow");
            });

        });

    </script>

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $('#show1').click(function () {
            var imageElement = document.getElementById('show1');
            if (imageElement.src.indexOf("Images/arrow1.png") != -1) {
                $("#show1").attr("src", "Images/rarrow1.png");
            } else {
                $("#show1").attr("src", "Images/arrow1.png");
            }
            $('#show-list1').toggle("slow");
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: This is the script I edited according to (@divvy3993) shared answer.

Thanks again mate